# Pandas: Fill missing dates in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, strftime

How do I fill the Date column so that when it detects a date it adds that date to the below rows, until it sees a new date starts adding that date?

Reproducible example:

Input:

```
                Date                                           Headline
0   Mar-20-21 04:03AM  Apple CEO Cook, executives on tentative list o...
1             03:43AM  Apple CEO Cook, execs on tentative list of wit...
2   Mar-19-21 10:19PM  Dow Jones Futures: Why This Market Rally Is So...
3             06:13PM  Zuckerberg: Apples Privacy Move Could Spur Mor...
4             05:45PM  Apple (AAPL) Dips More Than Broader Markets: W...
5             04:17PM  Facebook Stock Jumps As Zuckerberg Changes Tun...
6             04:03PM  Best Dow Jones Stocks To Buy And Watch In Marc...
7             01:02PM  The Nasdaq's on the Rise Friday, and These 2 S...
```

Desired Output:

```
                 Date                                           Headline
0   Mar-20-21 04:03AM  Apple CEO Cook, executives on tentative list o...
1   Mar-20-21 03:43AM  Apple CEO Cook, execs on tentative list of wit...
2   Mar-19-21 10:19PM  Dow Jones Futures: Why This Market Rally Is So...
3   Mar-19-21 06:13PM  Zuckerberg: Apples Privacy Move Could Spur Mor...
4   Mar-19-21 05:45PM  Apple (AAPL) Dips More Than Broader Markets: W...
5   Mar-19-21 04:17PM  Facebook Stock Jumps As Zuckerberg Changes Tun...
6   Mar-19-21 04:03PM  Best Dow Jones Stocks To Buy And Watch In Marc...
7   Mar-19-21 01:02PM  The Nasdaq's on the Rise Friday, and These 2 S...
```

Attempt:

```
df['Time'] = [x[-7:] for x in df['Date']]
df['Date'] = [x[:-7] for x in df['Date']]
# Some code that fills the date
# Then convert to datetime
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you use `ffill()` you need to split the two columns to get the correct time, and only fill in the Date part. You will need to replace spaces with `np.nan` to use `ffill()`. Then put the columns back together and wrap that operation in `pd.to_datetime` to get the correct `dtype`.

Lastly you can drop the time column.

```
# Imports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Split the column
df[['Date','Time']] = df['Date'].str.split(' ',expand=True)

# Replace space with nan and use ffill()
df['Date'] = df['Date'].replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True).ffill()

# Put the columns back and convert to datetime
df['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time'])

# Drop the time column
del(df['Time'])
```

Will get you back:

```
df
                 Date                                           Headline
0 2021-03-20 04:03:00  Apple CEO Cook, executives on tentative list o...
1 2021-03-20 03:43:00  Apple CEO Cook, execs on tentative list of wit...
2 2021-03-19 22:19:00  Dow Jones Futures: Why This Market Rally Is So...
3 2021-03-19 18:13:00  Zuckerberg: Apples Privacy Move Could Spur Mor...
4 2021-03-19 17:45:00  Apple (AAPL) Dips More Than Broader Markets: W...
5 2021-03-19 16:17:00  Facebook Stock Jumps As Zuckerberg Changes Tun...
6 2021-03-19 16:03:00  Best Dow Jones Stocks To Buy And Watch In Marc...
7 2021-03-19 13:02:00  The Nasdaq's on the Rise Friday, and These 2 S...
```

**EDIT**
If you want your 'Date' to show exactly as you have it in your desired outcome, i.e. this format 'Mar-20-21', don't wrap it in `pd.to_datetime()` and keep it as an `object`:

```
df['Date'] =  df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time']

df
                Date                                           Headline
0  Mar-20-21 04:03AM  Apple CEO Cook, executives on tentative list o...
1  Mar-20-21 03:43AM  Apple CEO Cook, execs on tentative list of wit...
2  Mar-19-21 10:19PM  Dow Jones Futures: Why This Market Rally Is So...
3  Mar-19-21 06:13PM  Zuckerberg: Apples Privacy Move Could Spur Mor...
4  Mar-19-21 05:45PM  Apple (AAPL) Dips More Than Broader Markets: W...
5  Mar-19-21 04:17PM  Facebook Stock Jumps As Zuckerberg Changes Tun...
6  Mar-19-21 04:03PM  Best Dow Jones Stocks To Buy And Watch In Marc...
7  Mar-19-21 01:02PM  The Nasdaq's on the Rise Friday, and These 2 S...
```

Comment: the solution works without this line: `df[['Date','Time']] = df['Date'].str.split(' ',expand=True)`. It gives me NaT with that line